# What is the difference among different levels of loggings in mule esb?

Tags: logging, mule, log4j2, mule-component

In mule esb when i drag logger component, i can see there are 5 log levels:

DEBUG, ERROR, INFO, TRACE and WARN. What is the difference among these 5 and when to use what?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

The log level defines the severity of the message. For example, ERROR indicates something that cannot be helped (e.g. "Missing attribute!") while WARN indicates something to be aware of (e.g. "Missing attribute, default value will be used.") and INFO is just a regular message you might want (e.g. "Starting process"). DEBUG and TRACE are usually meant to assist in the debugging of an application so they are usually more verbose (e.g. "Missing attribute 'myAttribute'. Default value of '3' will be used.").

The interesting part is that these are hierarchical so when you set the general log level from which to log, only messages with a log level equal or above the chosen one will show.

I recommend taking a look at [Mule documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/logging-in-mule) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_logging_framework#Severity_level) to understand a bit more about the levels since this is just general programming stuff.